# Does the expiry function still send after expiry time?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I can't figure this one out, maybe because I'm sending to myself.

If I set an expiry time on the message, does it still appear in the recipients inbox if they open their email client **after** the expiry time, or does it get deleted from the server if it's not dropped into the inbox before the expiry time?

Answer (score 0):

The email will still arrive in the recipients inbox.

However (assuming that the user hasn't changed their conditional formatting rules) it will be displayed in the inbox in grey with a line struck through it.

In addition, on opening the message, the window will warn the recipient that it has expired.